# Should applicants mention any dissertation or thesis in their CV?

Tags: interviewing, resume, qualification

I'm thinking to include my degree dissertations in my CV. I gather that this isn't the norm here in the UK, but they do seem somewhat relevant and seeing as I don't have much experience yet, it looks like a good way to beef up the resume a bit. Another answer [suggests mentioning the dissertation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/10353/9549) as an example of a project that you've worked on, but not on the resume itself.

For example:

**BSc in Computer Science** *1981 - 1984* 
University of Oceania 
Dissertation: *Efficient methods for republishing the Newspeak Dictionary*

- Have you ever done this as an applicant, or come across it as an employer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing your personal Resume/CV.  This is off topic.

Comment: @Chad I have not attended the University of Oceania, nor have I ever written a paper for the [Ministry of Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_Truth).

Comment: I mentioned my thesis on my CV, and that's the reason I now have my dream job, continuing that line of research.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Have you ever done this as an applicant, or come across it as an
>   employer?

I have never done this as an applicant, but I have seen it a few times as a hiring manager reviewing resumes.

If the dissertation is directly relevant to the job at hand, I have found it interesting, and have followed up with the candidate during the interview. At the time, I just discussed it with the candidate, and didn't actually read the dissertation.

If the dissertation is not directly relevant to the job at hand, then I just considered it clutter.

My feeling has always been that one should include only items which they feel are relevant to the job on their CV/Resume. (If "Republishing the Newspeak Dictionary" is something that could happen in the job for which you are applying, then it's directly relevant.)

If irrelevant items are included, I tend to wonder why, and mentally "take off points" from my rating. I know people are rightly proud of their accomplishments and want to share them widely, but I don't believe a resume is the proper place for that.

I feel the same way about things like Hobbies, Outside Interests, etc. If they are directly relevant and will help you get that job, include them. If not, leave them off.

Comment: I pretty much agree with Joe S. on this issue, but I would never consider a line about your dissertation to be 'clutter'.  That may be because when I interview people I'm looking for their capability to grow an adapt to change. So I'm not bothered if the disseration is not directly related to today's job opening. Someone else may just be looking for the peg that exactly fits today's hole and not want to know anything beyond that.  Big companies are often looking for perfectly formed pegs.

Comment: Unless you're applying for academic positions, a few jobs after graduation, it is probably clutter.

Comment: @JeffO but for a masters/phd the thesis is the major part of the work involved in a degree why would you not put the subject of your thesis.

Answer (score 3):

If you are at a standing start as a post-grad and creating a thesis and doing the research to support it, you are carrying out a process that looks suspiciously like system design and requirements gathering for a software project.  These are nearly identical processes, up to the point where you have to 'make things work' - typos might get past your advisor, but software tolerance for that is zero.

I sent a job application to a research institution in the late 1990s, they sent back a form asking me to list every submission I've had published in an academic journal. In some roles, such work is a baseline employment requirement.